# unicorn engine exception on mapped memory

Tags: mips, emulation, unicorn

I'm trying to emulate a MIPS 32 big-endian binary. Unfortunately, it throws an exception on the first instructions. I tried to start it from the second, and third instructions as well:

```
#!/bin/python3

from unicorn import *
from unicorn.mips_const import *

stack_size = 3 * 4096
load_address = 0x80023000
stack_base = load_address + 24*1024*1024 + 4096

def load_unicorn():
    mu = Uc(UC_ARCH_MIPS, UC_MODE_MIPS32 + UC_MODE_BIG_ENDIAN)
    er = open(r"blob", "rb")
    emulate_blob = er.read()
    mu.mem_map(load_address, 0x1000 + 24 * 1024 * 1024)
    mu.mem_map(stack_base, stack_size)
    mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_SP, stack_base + stack_size)

    mu.mem_write(load_address + 0xf00, emulate_blob)
    er.close()
    return mu

def decompress(mu):
    decompress_start = 0x800246AC
    decompress_end = 0x80024730

    buffer_address = 0x20000000
    buffer_size = 20 * 1024 * 1024 * 4 #0x2000000

    mu.mem_map(buffer_address, buffer_size)

    dest_buffer_address = buffer_address

    mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_A0, 0x8002917c)
    mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_A1, 0xD4AAEBC)
    mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_A2, dest_buffer_address)
    mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_A3, buffer_size)
    #mu.reg_write(UC_MIPS_REG_PC, decompress_start)

    mu.mem_write(stack_base, b"\x00" * stack_size)
    try:
        mu.emu_start(decompress_start, decompress_end)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("IP: 0x{:x}".format(mu.reg_read(UC_MIPS_REG_PC)))

    total_size = mu.reg_read(UC_MIPS_REG_S5)
    decompressed_data = mu.mem_read(dest_buffer_address, total_size)
    return decompressed_data

memory_unit = load_unicorn()
data = decompress(memory_unit)
```

When I read the memory at decompress_start (`print(mu.mem_read(decompress_start,1024))`), I get the following:
`bytearray(b'\'\xbd\x00(\'\xbd\xff\xb8\x8f\xa3...`
which corresponds correctly to the instructions in this code (\x27\xbd\xff\xb8 is `addiu sp, sp, -0x48`)

What could be wrong here? thanks!

Comment: What is `print(mu.mem_read(decompress_start,1024)))` supposed to print?

Comment: the memory content starts at address "decompress_start" and ends with decompress_start + 1024

Comment: The `addiu sp, sp, -0x48` looks like a function prologue to me. This is a common operation that C compilers will do to allocate room on the stack for local variables (the amount subtracted will vary depending on how many local variables the function has and how big they are.) Somehow, it seems that a function was copied to your memory range.

Comment: Isn't that what it is supposed to be? the is the first instruction of the function